# Adding IntegerMetaClass to GroovyShell dynamically

Tags: java, groovy, metaclass, groovyshell, groovyclassloader

I would like to use a custom `IntegerMetaClass` only in a given `GroovyShell` context.

The reason why is to not pollute the whole runtime with my potentially 'disturbing' `IntegerMetaClass`.

It works like a charm when I put my IntegerMetaClass.java implementation in the magic package `groovy.runtime.metaclass.java.lang`. But, when I try to add it manually to an intermediate GroovyClassLoader, it stops working.

```
// Pseudo-code without try catch, etc
// Within my eval factory
GroovyClassLoader gcl = new GroovyClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());
URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("groovy/runtime/metaclass/java/lang/IntegerMetaClass.groovy"); // I rename it to .groovy file
GroovyCodeSource gcs = new GroovyCodeSource(url);
Class<?> clazz = gcl.parseClass(gcs);
// clazz is not null here and equals to what I expect:
//   Class<groovy.runtime.metaclass.java.lang.IntegerMetaClass>

// Now trying to use it in a groovy shell
GroovyShell gs = new GroovyShell(gcl);
gs.evaluate("10.minutes"); // Where .minutes is part of my IntegerMetaClass
// Fail with an NoSuchProperty exception
```

Do I miss something to do on `GroovyClassLoader` more than just 'parsing' the MetaClass ? Anywhere else ?

**Update1:**

As mentioned above, `IntegerMetaClass.minutes` lookup is working when I put it directly in my java sources classpath.

```
package groovy.runtime.metaclass.java.lang;

import groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass;
import groovy.lang.MetaClass;

public class IntegerMetaClass extends DelegatingMetaClass {
    public IntegerMetaClass(Class<Integer> delegate) {
        super(delegate);
    }

    public IntegerMetaClass(MetaClass delegate) {
        super(delegate);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getProperty(Object object, String property) {
        if ("minutes".equals(property)) {
            Integer q = (Integer) object;
            return new Minutes(q);
        }
        return super.getProperty(object, property);
    }
}
```

**Update2:**

A possible but not satisfying solution :

Adding the following just after the `gcl.parseClass` call

```
Constructor<?> constructor = clazz.getConstructor(Class.class);
DelegatingMetaClass dmc = (DelegatingMetaClass) constructor.newInstance(Integer.class);
dmc.initialize();
InvokerHelper.getMetaRegistry().setMetaClass(Integer.class, dmc);
```

But this solution has to maintain a sort of 'mapping' between MetaClass sources and original targeted class to support more than `Integer` ...

Comment: Can you post your `IntegerMetaClass` source?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25974525/scope-of-groovys-metaclass

Comment: The thing is I don't want the user writing the evaluated groovy script to worry about 'meta configuring' classes before he use them.

Answer (score 1):

You can load the class with the `GroovyShell` classloader:

```
    GroovyShell gs = new GroovyShell()
    gs.loader.loadClass('groovy.runtime.metaclass.java.lang.IntegerMetaClass')
    gs.evaluate("10.minutes")
```

Note: I got a `java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError` when `IntegerMetaClass` was a groovy file but no issues when it was java. That could just be related to my environment setup